# Tag(s?) for other sciences

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[I just asked a question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/what-are-some-activities-projects-i-can-assign-to-calculus-students-from-bio-che) about motivating the interests of biology/chemistry/physics students and noticed there were no tags for those topics. I opted to create the "physical-sciences" tag, since I'm sure there will be more future questions about having students from these majors in mathematics courses.

**Would it be best to have individual tags for other subjects, like these? Or should we group these as one tag?**

Comment: I think such tags can make sense. However, when seeing the question I thought of a quite different intent, namely that the tag was for the other subjects  not for the students of the other subjects. One could also ask which physics (and so on) applications can be shown to *math students* and tag this physics. I think both types of tags could be useful. Or did you intend to use this one for both? I would prefer separate tags. Thus I would suggest a different name for the tag for students (maybe append -students).

Comment: So, something like "science-students" to be used on the question I posted?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'd suggest (or, also further specializing to physics-students or something like this).

Answer (score 1):

We already have a "computer-science" tag, and that makes sense, as I'm sure we'll have many questions that fit that topic. But I'm not sure whether we anticipate a bunch of specific biology questions, say. I believe I will ask at least a couple more questions like this one in the future, but I'm not sure it will ever be specific enough to merit only a "chemistry" tag. So, I suggest leaving it as is for now, and if folks come along with more pointed questions about an individual discipline, we can add tags as needed. But, I do feel my question, as stated, belongs to "physical-sciences", and it makes more sense right now to use that than to burn 3 of the 5 possible tags on "physics", "biology", "chemistry".

Comment: 'it makes more sense right now to use that than to burn 3 of the 5 possible tags on "physics", "biology", "chemistry".' But wouldn't this only apply to questions which are within the area of all three sciences? I'd rather have the clarity of using the exact name of the natural science in quesion.

Comment: @Roland: Understandable. So, should there be "science-students" and "physics-students" and "bio-students" and "chem-students"?

Comment: On a practical note: it is possible and easy to merge distinct tags (also renaming is possible). Conversely there is no way to split an existing tag later, except of course by retagging each question individually. Thus when in doubt and in general I would say let us start with specific ones and see how things develop.